# Why am i getting Object of type method is not JSON serializable when making this api call

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to interact with the coinbase api and keep getting "TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable" when trying to print out this json data, I know the get request is correct as it returns a 200 when I remove the json.dumps().

```
    import requests
    import json


    response = requests.get('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy')
    data = json.dumps(response.json)
    print(data)
```

Comment: really new to coding and would appreciate any help or advice

Comment: this is what im having a hard time wrapping my head around in the api documentation it seems the response should be a json format https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?python#:~:text=GET%20https%3A//api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/%3Acurrency_pair/buy

Comment: `response.json` is a method, it returns the result of *deserializing* JSON in the response. To get that, you can need to *call the method*: `response.json()`. But then, you are just going to *reserialize it*, so you just want `response.text`....

Answer (score 1):

Your return is:

```json
{'data': {'base': 'BTC', 'currency': 'USD', 'amount': '40880.98'}}
```

It has a JSON syntax error

Try this

```
response = requests.get('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy')
data = response.json()
dataJson = json.dumps(data['data'])
print(dataJson)
```

Comment: " It is Json syntax error " no, because **it isn't JSON**. It's the *result of deserializing JSON*

Comment: Yes. you are right.  Actually it isn't Json. I'm just saying it has error if you regard it as a json

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
response = requests.get('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy')
data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data)  # {'data': {'base': 'BTC', 'currency': 'USD', 'amount': '40935.10'}}
```

Comment: **why not just `response.json()`**???

Comment: You can use `.json()` if you are absolutely sure the result was written in JSON format, or it will raise an error.

Comment: Yours would raise *the exact same error*. And in any case, that isn't what is causing the OP's problem

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, I didn't notice that OP didn't call the method.